# Can a Circle be called a polygon with infinite number of sides?

Tags: geometry

Lets imagine i have made a square of sides 1 unit*1 unit and now i make a pentagon in it with all sides equal and now i keep adding sides with condition that length of all sides be same. So now lets say number of sides is close to infinity so would it become a circle at one point and how can we differentiate it from other inscribed polygon with MANY SIDES (NOT INFINITY)?

Comment: No, we can not. Polygon can not have infinitely many sides.

Comment: This is a great line of thinking for someone getting into the concept of limits at infinity.  Unfortunately, polygons have a finite number of sides.

Comment: You can call it that but that would be any oversimplification and could lead to some really sloppy poor thinking.... the main thing is what does 'number of sides tends to reach infinity" mean practically anyway?  It doesn't mean anything. A shape has a specific number of sides.  Numbers are what they are and do not "tend" toward anything.  A shape with 7 sides has 7 sides and a shape with 54368 sides has 54368  sides and the number of sides don't "tend" to anything else. If you talk of the *idea* or shapes when the number of sides gets big, is one thing but you must *define* what you mean.